# Thrift error in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, thrift

I am trying to get Thrift working in Eclipse and having some issues.  The project is a standard maven project.

I used the thrift compiler to compile the thrift file to Java code, which was successful.  The generated code was placed under src/main/generated-sources//

(Is this acceptable practise?)

In eclipse, I added the src folder from the build menu, but then I get:

```
Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method from ProcessFuction<I,...
```

I am not using the maven thrift plugin as the source is already generated and within the source tree (again, is this advisable?).

How should I configure this setup?

Comment: I have found the issue with the error.  The thrift compiler and the included library (libthrift) were not the same.  My question above is therefore reduced to whether the generated code location and not using the thrift plugin is acceptable practise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

seems like the Thrift compiler is not as good as thought.

*Cannot reduce the visibility of the inherited method*

shows that a inherited method from an abstract class or an interface has originally a higher visibility, e.g. "public" while you have "private" in your code.

I would try to set that to "public" and see what happens. The code might compile sweet, as I expect that mismatch to be generated due to compiling/transformation of code with missing visibility setting on the method as one can write a method header without specifying the visiblitiy:

```
void doany(){
   // nothing
}
```

The method uses the classes visibility in that case (mostly "public") - which the compiler will have misunderstood.

Comment: Not quite, it is quite good... it is just not backwards compatible.  The code was generated with 0.8, while the library included was 0.9.  Once I changed the library to 0.8 it worked fine.

Comment: cool. please mark the question as answered, so others can find that solution.

Comment: "*please mark the question as answered, so others can find that solution*" - the OP answers his own question and marks your answer that doesn't even solve the issue as "the" answer? What kind of crude logic is that?